# Cannot execute stored procedure in Oracle with different database user returns ora-00997 error

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc

I have written a stored procedure in Oracle database which returns data as a
TABLE type object. I read this data in a Java program using java.sql.Array and java.sql.Struct.
I created this stored procedure under a database user A.
This stored procedure works fine and returns data as expected.
The java program connects to the database with user A and is able to read the data obtained from the stored procedure.
Public synonyms have been created for the Type objects as well as the stored procedure and suitable grant permissions have been given to a group of database users.

However, when I execute the java program by connecting to the database as user B (another valid database user part of the database user group), I get the following exception

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00997: illegal use of LONG datatype
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:445)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:879)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:192)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:531)
```

I am getting the above exception when i am getting data from callablestatement after a successful call to execute().
I am able to execute the stored procedure through SQL Plus tool though (connect as user B).
Any hint/help would be great.

Type definitions are as below

```
CREATE TYPE gbm_test_type AS OBJECT
(
encounter_id NUMBER(12),
bed_number VARCHAR2(10)
);
/

CREATE TYPE gbm_test_type_tab IS TABLE OF gbm_test_type;
/
```

Procedure specification is as below

```
CREATE PACKAGE GBM_TEST_TYPE_PKG as
procedure GBM_TEST_TYPE_SP(v_Str in varchar2,
op_type_tab out gbm_test_type_tab);
end GBM_TEST_TYPE_PKG;
/


CREATE PACKAGE BODY GBM_TEST_TYPE_PKG as
PROCEDURE GBM_TEST_TYPE_SP(v_Str in varchar2,
op_type_tab out gbm_test_type_tab)
IS

op_tab gbm_test_type_tab := gbm_test_type_tab();
op_icon_rec gbm_test_type;

err_msg VARCHAR2(10000):= '';

BEGIN
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('INSIDE PROC '||v_Str);
    BEGIN
        -- initializing to hard coded values        
        op_icon_rec := gbm_test_type(1,'temp');
        op_tab.extend;
        op_tab(1) := op_icon_rec;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
          err_msg := 'FAILURE WHILE INITIALIZING TEMP O/P RECORD--'|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 100);
    END;

-- finally set the ouput
op_type_tab := op_tab;

-- global exception handling
EXCEPTION 
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('failure message '|| SUBSTR(SQLERRM, 1 , 100));

END GBM_TEST_TYPE_SP;

END GBM_TEST_TYPE_PKG;
/
```

Java code snippet is as below

```
String spCallString = "{call GBM_TEST_SPS_PKG.GBM_TEST_SPS(?,?)}";
        spCallString = "{call GBM_TEST_TYPE_PKG.GBM_TEST_TYPE_SP(?,?)}";
        CallableStatement callStmt = null;
        try {
            callStmt = conn.prepareCall(spCallString);  
                        // set data to callable statement
                        callStmt.execute();

                        Object opObj = callStmt.getObject(2);// output is at index 2
                        if (opObj instanceof Array) {
            Array opArr = (Array) opObj;

                        Object val = opArr.getArray(); // this is the line throwing error

                        // further processing
                  } catch (SQLException e) {
                  // handle exception
                  } finally{
                   // handle resource release
                  }
```

Giving some more context to the problem:
I have another set of Type objects and a package (with stored procedure) which gets me some other data. The style followed is the same.
Type -> used in stored procedure -> executed in java code
I am able to execute and get data from this stored procedure in java code if i use database user A or user B.

Thanks and Regards
s.r.guruprasad

Comment: You're sure it's coming from the execute of that procedure, not processing the response or at some other point? Does the procedure reference any tables with `long` columns? Showing at least the type definitions and procedure specification might help. It sounds like it's hitting its own version of the proc, but being able to run it through SQL*Plus as the same user scuppers that; unless you change `current_schema` when you log in, though a `login.sql` or `glogin.sql` perhaps.

Comment: The problem is happening when I am processing data from callablestatement.  I have tried creating a simple stored procedure which does nothing but initialize the table of type objects and return this table type. Even this simple stored procedure is not giving results.

Comment: As Alex said, try `select * from dba_objects where object_name = 'GBM_TEST_TYPE_SP'` and it will show if there are multiple procedures with this name. If this error is thrown, it has to be common for any user id.

Comment: I executed the SQL query - did get records for the package. I got 2 records for the package - one for the package and the other for package body. I did not get any record for the stored procedure though. I was able to verify this with user A. user B does not have rights to query dba_objects.

Comment: Does schema B have its own types defined? Even if it had `gbm_test_type` it shouldn't normally matter to the procedure; but how are you linking the type to the array definition on the Java side? If that is picking up schema B's type definition that could have odd effects, but I would think it would give a more helpful error as it would be a type mismatch.

Comment: schema B does not have its own types. User A is the DBA user. I log in as A and create the Types and the stored procedures. I have created public synonyms and grant suitable permissions on Types and stored procedures to a user group which contains user B. There is a web application which connects to the database as user B. A functionality in this application depends on the stored procedure and the execution of this stored procedure fails.

Comment: On the java side,I register an output parameter with the callablestatement of Types.Array type and pass the Type name as the argument. I then read the data using java.sql.Array and java.sql.Struct as already mentioned. There is only one definition of the Type in the database and the java web application only connects to the database as B (normal user). Expectation is that the  Type and the stored procedures will get picked up in the database side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution for this issue.
The cause of this issue was due to the Type definition i had.
I have another stored procedure which makes use of an extended Type definition and this
stored procedure works fine (when I get the connection as user B as well).
Type B (final) extends Type A (not final) is the structure used.
The Type structure used in the stored procedure having this issue is
Type C (not final).
If i change the Type structure to Type D(final) extends Type C (not final),
then the stored procedure executes fine and data is returned when I get connection
as user B as well.
I tested with Type E(final) but still was not able to retrieve data from stored procedure.
I even created test Types to verify this solution.
This seems to be an issue with Oracle JDBC implementation jar.

My general expectation would be that a final Type should be used properly internally and data should be returned.